# Searching AD Groups attached to specified Server

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm looking to use powershell, specify a server hostname, and have it display all the AD Groups that have access to that server. From there I'll dig into the groups eventually getting the usernames and storing them in a csv file.

So far I have the code to get the DN of the server -

```
Get-adcomputer HOSTNAME | select DistinguishedName
```

Along with having the code to get the eventual usernames and store them in a csv -

```
$groups= GROUPS
$selectgroups=$groups |Get-Adgroup
$selectgroups |get-adgroupmember -Recursive | Select samaccountname |
Export-csv -path C:\Groups\Members.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

My problem is I can't figure out how to get powershell to query what groups are on the server I specify. Is this possible or will I have to look at another way of doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I'm rather new to powershell so didn't realise that would work. Thanks! My next problem is that I want to run this from a desktop and not the server itself that I'm querying. Have any insight into what I should go and study to get an idea for that? Thanks again.

Comment: I don't understand. It isn't possible to get a list of all AD Groups that have permissions on a specific server. You could go through all file, registry and share ACLs, local Groups etc. and find AD Groups that are members/have permissions, but there could also be Third party Applications, web.config files etc. that uses AD-Groups. You need to be more specific. Active Directory only knows who's member of a Group, not where you've used it.

Comment: I reread this an my comment is not what you are looking for. Please read Frode's comment and answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you know exactly what you're looking for.  There's no way to tell which AD groups have been granted access to a node via AD.  The only thing you can do is look on the local node for AD groups, but there's a lot of places you could want/need to look as Frode F. mentioned already.  A common theme would be which AD groups have been added to LOCAL groups on the node in question.

You could use WMI or the ADSI adapter for this information.  An ADSI example to get all members of the 'Administrators' local group for server 'NODE123':

```
    $server = "NODE123"
    $arrGroupMembers=@()
    $Group = "Administrators"
    $ADSIComputer = [ADSI]("WinNT://" + $server + ",computer") 
    $ADSIGroup = $ADSIcomputer.psbase.children.find($Group) 
    $ADSIMembers= $ADSIGroup.psbase.invoke("Members")
    foreach ($member in $ADSIMembers) {   
        $MemberClass = $member.GetType().InvokeMember("Class", 'GetProperty', $Null, $member, $Null)
        if ($memberClass -eq "Group") {
            $MemberName = $member.GetType().InvokeMember("Name", 'GetProperty', $Null, $member, $Null)
            $arrGroupMembers+=$MemberName
        }
    }
```

With the array return above, you now have all groups that have access to NODE123 via being added to the local Administrators group.  Maybe this example helps you.